# Backbone Js Delete is not working properly

Tags: rest, codeigniter, backbone.js

I am developing an application using CodeIgniter rest application and backbone.js.

I am trying to delete a record from the database. The backbone model returns success callback, the database data is not getting deleted.

```
    $("#deleteItem").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("toing" + deleteItemID);

        var deleteUserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: "http://localhost/WishListApplication/index.php/listItem/removeItem",
            defaults: {
                userId: '',
                itemURL: ''

            }
        });

        var removeItem = new deleteUserModel({userId: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('userId'); ?>,
            itemURL: deleteItemID});

        removeItem.destroy(
                {
                    success: function (model, response, options) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#delete-item').modal('hide');

                        console.log("The model has deleted the server");
                    },
                    error: function (model, xhr, options) {
                        console.log("Something went wrong while deleting the model");
                    }
                });



    });
```

This is my controller class

```
public function removeItem_delete() {
    $userId = $this->delete('userId');

    $itemURL = $this->delete('itemURL');


    $deletedItem = $this->itemModel->deleteItem($userId, $itemURL);

    //checks whether item has successfully deleted from the database
    if ($deletedItem !== false) {
        //display sucess message
        $data['messages'] = 'Item has been deleted successfully';
        $data['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $data['messages'] = 'Something went wrong - Please try to delete Item again';
        $data['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I am new to backbone. please some one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check if your example is correct: function in url_Root is removeItem, function in your controller is removeItem_delete ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am extending 'REST_Controller'. Not CI_Controller